# Material3 - how to transform MediumTopAppBar to CenterAlignedTopAppBar on scroll

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material3

In Material3 components documentation ([link](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/guidelines#0e9878bc-c1e1-46a5-afa5-4b43a1949dc1)) there is an example video of how `MediumTopAppBar` is changed during scroll to `CenterAlignedTopAppBar`. Description also explains: "When scrolling up, Medium top app bars can use the compress effect to transform into Compact top app bars. They should not return to Medium size until the user scrolls back to the top of the page."

I've tried to implement `MediumTopAppBar`. It transforms to `SmallTopAppBar` without any issues, but I can't seem to figure out how to transform it to `CenterAlignedTopAppBar`.

I can't seem to find any examples or detailed documentation as to how this can be achieved.
Any ideas as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: `titleHorizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start` seems to be hardcoded

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yes, but the provided video example clearly shows how medium app bar transforms to center aligned top app bar.

Comment: It is the M3 documentation in general, not the Compose API documentation.